# How to extend distutils with a simple pre uninstall script?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I found [Question#1321270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321270/how-to-extend-distutils-with-a-simple-post-install-script) for post install. My main target for the moment is bdist_wininst, but i did not find anything related to uninstall...

For clarification:
I want to register a com server after installation and de-register it before uninstall.

**Extended answer:**
ars' answer seems correct, however, for the completeness of things (I think the docs leave some room for improvements on this topic...):
I have NOT as was suggested by mention of [Question#1321270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321270/how-to-extend-distutils-with-a-simple-post-install-script) extended `distutils.command.install`, but written a new python sript called `scripts/install.py` and set the following in setup.py:

```
setup(
    ...
    scripts=['scripts\install.py'],
    options = {
        ...
        "bdist_wininst" : {
            "install_script" : "install.py", 
            ...
        },
    }
)
```

The install.py is definitively being called on install. It seems, though that it is (despite to what the docs say) not being called on uninstall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same post-install script will run at uninstall with different arguments.  See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html#the-postinstallation-script) for more info:

> This script will be run at installation time on the target system after all the files have been copied, with argv[1](http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html#the-postinstallation-script) set to -install, and again at uninstallation time before the files are removed with argv[1](http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html#the-postinstallation-script) set to -remove.

Comment: looks correct, but does not happen. Is it possible that the unistallation part is not correct for bdist_wininst ??

Comment: I think the script has to be in the root directory (your setup indicates it's under a "scripts" folder).

Comment: No, regardless of where the script resides (root, subdirectory) it is only used in post-install, never in pre-uninstall. This happens on Win7, amd64. I'll try on WinXP, x86 tonight.

Comment: I thinkt this is a correct answer as it's what the docs say _should_ work…

Comment: There is a known Python bug that causes this not to work: see http://bugs.python.org/issue13276