# Run post-install script in a Python Egg (setuptools)

Tags: python, linux, egg

I have created a little Python egg (with setuptools) that I want to install in other machines of my LAN. I have even setup a server for the eggs and all (and the egg is properly downloaded and installed with `easy_install -f http://myserver/eggrepository` ) :-)

I would like to know if there's a way of running an script (bash or Python) when installing it with easy_install (version 0.6c11 and python2.6).

I have added a bash script to the package, and I'd like to be able to run it automatically (mainly to start some functionalities in the rcX.d levels, start running at startup, etc...) when the egg is installed. Right now I have to go to the /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages, find the folder where my egg was installed and run the bash script that is in said egg... But that solution is not very accurate and I'm sure it will give me problems if I change versions, paths, etc...

I've been reading and I found some posts saying it wasn't possible, but they are a bit old and maybe there's a way now... I also found others saying it was possible with distutils (which means that probably setuptools can do it too) but I haven't been able to find any suitable solution using setuptools.

Thank you in advance

Related:

[How can I add post install scripts...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250038/how-can-i-add-post-install-scripts-to-easy-install-setuptools-distutils)

[How to extend distutils with a simple post install script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321270/how-to-extend-distutils-with-a-simple-post-install-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I found a workaround...
[python-packaging-custom-scripts](http://parijatmishra.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/python-packaging-custom-scripts/)

It's not as straight-forward as I would have liked, but well... 
I can put the installation process in an sh file and then, since there's going to be a Python script in the user's path, I can call it from the bash script installing the package...