# How to include the module generated by SWIG after executing setup in Python

Tags: python, swig, distutils, setup.py

The [Python setup documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#extension-source-files) suggests for SWIG the following:

```
setup(...,
      ext_modules=[Extension('_foo', ['foo.i'],
                             swig_opts=['-modern', '-I../include'])],
      py_modules=['foo'],
     )
```

However, the generated file is not immediately copied to the path. Some people suggest executing two times the setup (so the module is already generated). [Others installing via scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864342/run-post-install-script-in-a-python-egg-setuptools) or subclassing the [install command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321270/how-to-extend-distutils-with-a-simple-post-install-script). Are there any good practices to address this issue with remote installations in mind (clusters) ?