# distutils - How to add a .pyw script if windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, distutils

I am distributing a simple library/application which includes a script with GUI. Under windows I want this to be run by pythonw.exe, preferrably by making it a `.pyw` file.

```
root/
    lib/
        lib.py

    guiscript.py
    setup.py
```

I want the user to be able to install `guiscript` in any path.

I stole this hook from [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321270/how-to-extend-distutils-with-a-simple-post-install-script)

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.install import install
import os, sys

class my_install(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        try:
            if (sys.platform == "win32") and sys.argv[1] != "-remove":
                os.rename("guiscript.py",
                          "guiscript.pyw")
        except IndexError:pass

setup(...
      cmdclass={"install": my_install})
```

But this doesn't work because it changes the name of guiscript.py in the source folder, because the path is relative to setup.py.

Is there a reasonable way to get the script install-path, or alternativly a simple way to find guiscript.py (it's not given it's in PYTHONPATH).

---

So because I don't have 50 karma i can't answer my own post in 7 hours but here it is:

Okay, I found the solution. I can delete the question if you want, but for now I'll keep it in case someone else has the same question.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.install_scripts import install_scripts
import os, sys

class my_install(install_scripts):
    """Change main script to .pyw after installation.

    If sys.argv == '-remove'; it's ran as uninstall-script.
    Override run() and then call parent."""
    def run(self):
        install_scripts.run(self)
        try:
            if (sys.platform == "win32") and sys.argv[1] != "-remove":
                for script in self.get_outputs():
                    if script.endswith("guiscript.py"):
                        os.rename(script, script+"w")
        except IndexError:pass

setup(...
      cmdclass={"install_scripts": my_install}
     )
```

Comment: Here are 3 links that contain some useful info re: your problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689015/run-python-script-without-dos-shell-appearing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813872/running-a-process-in-pythonw-with-popen-without-a-console
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390762/how-do-i-eliminate-windows-consoles-from-spawned-processes-in-python-2-7