# Execute a Python script post install using distutils / setuptools

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, distutils, post-install

**Note:** `distutils` is deprecated and the accepted answer has been updated to use `setuptools`

I'm trying to add a post-install task to Python distutils as described in [How to extend distutils with a simple post install script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321270/how-to-extend-distutils-with-a-simple-post-install-script/1321345). The task is supposed to execute a Python script *in the installed lib directory*. This script generates additional Python modules the installed package requires.

My first attempt is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.install import install

class post_install(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        from subprocess import call
        call(['python', 'scriptname.py'],
             cwd=self.install_lib + 'packagename')

setup(
 ...
 cmdclass={'install': post_install},
)
```

This approach works, but as far as I can tell has two deficiencies:

1. If the user has used a Python interpreter other than the one picked up from `PATH`, the post install script will be executed with a *different* interpreter which might cause a problem.
2. It's not safe against dry-run etc. which I might be able to remedy by wrapping it in a function and calling it with `distutils.cmd.Command.execute`.

How could I improve my solution? Is there a recommended way / best practice for doing this? I'd like to avoid pulling in another dependency if possible.

Comment: For those who want to be able to use also `python setup.py install`, as well as `pip install`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915469/python-setuptools-install-requires-is-ignored-when-overriding-cmdclass

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The way to address these deficiences is:

1. Get the full path to the Python interpreter executing `setup.py` from `sys.executable`.
2. Classes inheriting from `setuptools.Command` (such as `setuptools.command.install.install` which we use here) implement the `execute` method, which executes a given function in a "safe way" i.e. respecting the dry-run flag.

   Note however that [the `--dry-run` option is currently broken](https://bugs.python.org/issue8501) and does not work as intended anyway.

I ended up with the following solution:

```
import os, sys
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install as _install


def _post_install(dir):
    from subprocess import call
    call([sys.executable, 'scriptname.py'],
         cwd=os.path.join(dir, 'packagename'))


class install(_install):
    def run(self):
        _install.run(self)
        self.execute(_post_install, (self.install_lib,),
                     msg="Running post install task")


setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'install': install},
)
```

Note that I use the class name `install` for my derived class because that is what `python setup.py --help-commands` will use.

Comment: thanks, this really helped out,  I also needed to follow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853058/run-custom-task-when-call-pip-install) to avoid an error in my pip install.  I put it all together in a blog post (http://diffbrent.ghost.io/correctly-adding-nltk-to-your-python-package-using-setup-py-post-install-commands/).  Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: @brent.payne Glad to hear it helped! Note my comment on why I used `install` as class name.

Comment: it works, but I wasn't been able to have the custom install executed with `pip install -e name`. ps, just found [this link](http://www.niteoweb.com/blog/setuptools-run-custom-code-during-install), see the BONUS section.

Comment: Looks very good, the post install part still runs fine with `setuptools` instead of `distutils`, but the ability of `setuptools` to handle dependencies seems to be lost (they are just ignored).

Comment: @Paolo 's link has moved to: https://blog.niteo.co/setuptools-run-custom-code-in-setup-py/

Comment: Since [distutils is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753678/913098), how would this solution change for setuptools?

Comment: `setuptools` is a compatible replacement for `distutils`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to perform the post-install, and keep the requirements, is to decorate the call to `setup(...)`:

```
from setup tools import setup


def _post_install(setup):
    def _post_actions():
        do_things()
    _post_actions()
    return setup

setup = _post_install(
    setup(
        name='NAME',
        install_requires=['...
    )
)
```

This will run `setup()` when declaring `setup`. Once done with the requirements installation, it will run the `_post_install()` function, which will run the inner function `_post_actions()`.

Comment: this code seems don't work as desired... it will directly run the _post_action ...