# Using setuptools to install files to arbitrary locations

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

Is there a way to install files to arbitrary locations with setuptools?  I've used [Data Files](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) with setuptools before, but those are typically installed inside the package directory.  I need to install a plugin file that will be located in the install directory of another application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that setuptools has purposely made it difficult to install files outside of the package directory.

I instead included the plugin files as package data and used the [Entry Points](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#entry-points) feature of setuptools to expose the install/uninstall functions for the plugin files I wanted to distribute.

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mypackage_install_plugins = mypackage:install_plugins',
            'mypackage_uninstall_plugins = mypackage:uninstall_plugins',
        ],                
    }
)
```

I just added an additional step to the installation instructions to run the following command after installing the python package:

```
$> mypackage_install_plugins
```

Answer (score 1):

The [data_files](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) attribute will allow you to specify full paths.
You could also do some shutil.copy magic in your setup.py, except don't.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to work for most locations; though, it doesn't seem to allow paths within another package inside the site-packages directory, which is the case for the Qt Designer plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer:

[Execute a Python script post install using distutils / setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806485/execute-a-python-script-post-install-using-distutils-setuptools)

which shows how to add an arbitrary install script (python, shell, whatever) that runs at the end of the install.  It'll run whther you use "setup.py install" directly, or a package manager like "pip install".  With this, you can add any files you want, anywhere you want.

Unfortunately, I feel Brendan's pain - setuptools, not being a full package manager itself, does not handle the uninstall.  Therefore, there's no way to have an uninstall hook to reverse what you did in the post-install script.