# Ubuntu 22.04: Is it possible to get the directory of a specific nautilus window in a script?

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus, wmctrl

I have tried to use this: [Is it possible to get the directory of a specific nautilus window in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070465/is-it-possible-to-get-the-directory-of-a-specific-nautilus-window-in-a-script)

I used

```
sudo apt install python3-nautilus
```

and then followed the suggestions in the previous post for building an extension: `~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/extension.py`:

```
from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject, Gtk

class ColumnExtension(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.LocationWidgetProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_widget(self, uri, window):
        window.set_title(uri)
```

While there's a pycache, perhaps indicating that the extension is running, the window title (`wmctrl -lxp`) doesn't show the full path.

How do I get this solution running under Ubuntu 22.04?