# Finding setup.py installation dir within setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py, post-install

I'm writing a Python **setup.py** script that needs to fix up directory permissions after the installation is complete.  I'm using the **_postInstall()** hook mechanism to give me a place to invoke some final permission-setting code as the last thing in the installation.

However, I can't find any programmatic way to determine where in the file system the package was actually installed, e.g., */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages* or something.  setup.py can install your package in a vast number of different places depending on site, version, and command-line options.  (Interestingly, it turns out that the current directory in effect when the _postInstall() hook runs is actually a temp directory, not the install location, so no clue there.)

It seems amazing and astonishing that there isn't something in the Python environment I can reference to obtain this crucial info, but I am at a loss.

Comment: You might find an answer with http://stackoverflow.com/a/18159969

Comment: Thanks, Tynn.  I had already looked through this post.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am encountering this absurd problem myself right now.