# Execute a Python script post install using setuptools

Tags: python, installation, pip, setuptools, distutils

This is exactly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17806485/913098).

The [accepted (and only) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18159969/913098) uses `distutils` [which is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753678/913098).

Simply replacing `from distutils.core import setup` with `from setuptools import setup`

and `from setuptools.command import install as _install` with `from distutils.command.install import install as _install`

is not enough, because api differs.

---

I am looking for a solution using setuptools.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+post-install+script

Comment: Note: The solution in the duplicate answer **only works when installing a source distribution** zip or tarball, or installing in editable mode from a source tree. **It will not work when installing from a binary wheel (`.whl`)**

Comment: @phd how to make it also work for `.whl`?

Comment: No way. `pip` runs code from `setup.py` during build phase but it doesn't run `setup.py` during installation. And wheel format doesn't have provisions for post-install/pre-uninstall scripts. Source distributions (sdist) is the only way.